# Cannot find symbol method setVisibility(int)

Tags: android, push-notification, ibeacon-android

I am trying to build a notification method that would result in a notification appearing on the locked screen when a particular beacon is detected.  My understanding is that I need to include .setVisibility(0) in the following code:

```
public void showNotification(Beacon beacon) {

    Resources r = getResources();
    int random = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
            .setContentTitle("Beacons Found")
            .setContentText(beacon.getID().toString())
            .setVisibility(0)  // allow notification to appear on locked screen
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(random, notification);

}
```

I have the above code, but when I run it it says "Cannot find symbol method setVisibility(int)".  I have done some research online and it seems I need to import these:

```
 import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
 import android.app.Notification;
 import android.app.NotificationManager;
```

Even if I include these imports, I still get the same error message.  Can anyone help? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

setVisibility() was added in Api 21 According to documentation I found may try this.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

  Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
        .setContentTitle("Beacons Found")
        .setContentText(beacon.getID().toString())
        .setVisibility(0)  // allow notification to appear on locked screen
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(random, notification);

}
```

Comment: As he's using NotificationCompat, he should target API 22 so you should change your version code to LOLLIPOP_MR1 :)

Comment: Thanks both, I tried to add the above code but it says "cannot find symbol variable Lollipop "....  what do I need to do to solve this?

Comment: It should not get error. Please sync project and clean then rebuild the project.  If error any then what gradle error you get?

Comment: sorry I am very new to android studio... how to I sync project and clean then rebuild project?  Can you share any links that would guide me to do these?  I tried rebuilt project by clicking Build>rebuild project, and the error is still "cannot find symbol variable LOLLIPOP".

Comment: I went to Tools>Android>Sync project with Gradle files;  then click Build> Clean Project; then Build> Rebuild project.  However, after all these, still get  "cannot find symbol variable LOLLIPOP"